# files.whl is not sopported wheel on this plataform

Tags: python, anaconda

como puedo instalar esto paquetes en mi pc? ninguno de ellos me permite instalarlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y el warning que te da antes de que el fichero no existe?

Comment: perdon hice la captura antes de ver que estaban mal los nombre, pero el error de que no lo soporta la platarforma todavia esta.

Comment: Qué versión  de windows estás ocupando? Y qué versión de python?

Comment: tengo windows 7, python 3.7.6

Comment: Ese wheel es para python 3.6. O cambias tu versión de python o bajas un wheel para python 3.7

Comment: gracias, lo voy intentar y te aviso, como hago para saber que version del wheel es compatible con el python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la guía de etiquetado [PEP 425](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/), ese wheel que estás tratando de instalar `boost_python-1.67-cp36-c36m-win_amd64.whl` dice que:

1. `boost_python`: nombre del paquete
2. `1.67`: versión del paquete
3. `cp36`: implementación y versión de python requerida, acá es CPython 3.6
4. `c36m`: versión de Python ABI requerida, Python 3.6 --with-pymalloc
5. `win_amd64`: versión del sistema operativo para la cuál está pensado, o sea, Win-64bits
6. `whl`: es un wheel

Si el error dice **files.whl is not sopported wheel on this plataform** es muy probable que alguno de los requisitos (`cp36p`, `c36m`, `win_amd64`) no se esté cumpliendo. Según la información recién entregada tu versión de python es la 3.7 así que busca un paquete wheel que diga `boost_python-1.67-cp37-c37m-win_amd64.whl`(o tal vez `boost_python-1.67-cp37-c37-win_amd64.whl`)